# Compare two list of byte array

Tags: java

Is there any elegant way to compare if two list of byte[] is equals without looping all the elements ? I have tried `equals`, `Objects.equals`, `Objects.deepEquals,` but neither worked.

```
@Test
public void testListByteArray() {
  final String textStr1 = "test1";
  final String textStr2 = "test2";

  List<byte[]> a = Arrays.asList(textStr1.getBytes(), textStr2.getBytes());
  List<byte[]> b = Arrays.asList(textStr1.getBytes(), textStr2.getBytes());

  Assert.assertTrue(a.size() == b.size());

  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(a.get(i), b.get(i)));
  }

  Assert.assertTrue(a.equals(b)); //fail
  Assert.assertTrue(Objects.equals(a, b)); //fail
  Assert.assertTrue(Objects.deepEquals(a, b)); //fail
}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a significantly more elegant solution.  You might consider using Java 8+ streams, but the streams APIs don't provide an elegant way of comparing two lists element by element.  And as you observed `Objects.equals` and `Objects.deepEquals` don't work.  They both end up using `Object::equals` on the arrays ... which is equivalent to `==`.

Comment: I've found an (almost) duplicate for this.  Its just that I disagree that the solution it suggests is better than an explicit loop.  Elegance is a matter of opinion.

Comment: There is one workaround:  store ByteBuffers in your Lists instead of byte arrays.  Unlike arrays, [ByteBuffer defines an equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) which will compare content, allow you to compare the Lists using `a.equals(b)`.